# select query with where in the sub query

Tags: sql

i have query select for report like this,

```
select * from (

select *
FROM
  CTIORASQL.time_sheet ts
  LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        emp.employee_id,
        SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN emp.main_company_id = 9 
            THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN sce.schedule_type_id=1 THEN sce.total_minute
                END
            WHEN sce.activity_id = 21 THEN sce.total_minute
       END)/60 utl_tot
    FROM CTIORASQL.time_sheet ts
        LEFT JOIN CTIORASQL.time_sheet_schedule sce ON ts.time_sheet_id = sce.time_sheet_id
        LEFT JOIN CTIORASQL.m_employee emp ON ts.requester_id = emp.employee_id
        where ts.schedule_date BETWEEN '02-02-2020' and '07-10-2020'
        GROUP BY emp.employee_id
  ) utl ON utl.employee_id = emp.employee_id
  
)
where ts.schedule_date BETWEEN '02-02-2020' and '07-10-2020'
```

i have same where in the sub query, how to make where condition to just one condition? thankyou
in the condition i cannot put the sql code to back end, ijust use sqldeveloper tools

Comment: ts.schedule_date will not be accessible from the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for the outer query. It seems same as the subquery. Just use subquery for your desired result:

```
select *
FROM
  CTIORASQL.time_sheet ts
  LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        emp.employee_id,
        SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN emp.main_company_id = 9 
            THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN sce.schedule_type_id=1 THEN sce.total_minute
                END
            WHEN sce.activity_id = 21 THEN sce.total_minute
       END)/60 utl_tot
    FROM CTIORASQL.time_sheet ts
        LEFT JOIN CTIORASQL.time_sheet_schedule sce ON ts.time_sheet_id = sce.time_sheet_id
        LEFT JOIN CTIORASQL.m_employee emp ON ts.requester_id = emp.employee_id
        where ts.schedule_date BETWEEN '02-02-2020' and '07-10-2020'
        GROUP BY emp.employee_id
  ) utl ON utl.employee_id = emp.employee_id
```

If you have any other purpose for the outer query please explain.